# UIWebView incorrect display site, javascripts don't load after loading page

Tags: javascript, ios, css, uiwebview, xamarin

I use `UIWebView` in my app. And only one [site](http://shop.coles.com.au/online/mobile/qld-metro-the-gap/logon) load without css styles (only mobile version, with desktop all alright). I try load this site in Safari on my iOS device, all good. There is problem only with webView.
Doesn't help load with UIWebView `LoadRequest` method or transition to this page from full version of site.
Source code of this site has tag `<noscript>` and text from this tag shown on this webview.
It's look like something don't let download all scripts and styles, because in Chrome I looked source code of full loaded mobile site and it has more scripts, then page in WebView.

Moreover, I tried change `UIWebView` to the `WKWebView`, the problem remained. Also I use `Xamarin.Forms` and tried `Forms.WebView` - nothing. Is it a problem with code of site?

Comment: How it looks in UIWebview, can i have printscreen ?

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/do8jrm.jpg - Site at UIWebView
http://i59.tinypic.com/2r5t6jd.jpg - Site at Safari

Comment: Have you implement any delegate of UIWebview  or can i show code ?

Comment: No, I didn't implement any delegates. This problem appear even at new project with new object of UIWebView without any customization. And  with both WKWebView and Xamarin.Forms.WebView.